# python 3.x readlines()

Tags: python-3.x, readlines

After a pause I've currently started to work with python again but right at the start I encountered an annoying (and at least for me not solvable...) problem. I want to open a normal .txt file with tabular content so I can iterate over specific 'columns' to gather all the information I need. The problem is that I don't get each line of the document as a list but instead python creates strings of each line.I also tried .readlines() but thats doesn't work either.
I work on a Win7 PC and the code goes as followed:

```
with open('C:\\filepath...\\file.txt') as file:
 for f in file:
  print(f[0])
```

I also have to add that I also worked with python in the past and never encountered such problem so if anyone knows a solution I would really appreciate some help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are your lines have separated with a particular delimiter? can you show some sample lines of your file?

Comment: You should use `for line in file: for column in line.split('\t'):`

Comment: @Kasramvd: I think that's what he meant by *tabular content*: the lines are delimited by tabs.

Comment: @zondo It seems so, who knows? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to split:

```
TheList = []
with open('C:\\filepath...\\file.txt') as file:
    for f in file:
        TheList.append(f.split('\t'))
```